# JQuery copying value into a div class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Absolutely going out of my mind. It sounds like a very simple thing to do, but just can't get it to work!

Basically, I have a hidden input field result of the JQuery UI Datepicker. I have made the input type hidden, when I select a date it populates the Value field, and I want to now take that 'value' and place it in a div.

Anyone able to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have markup like this:

```
<input id="date" type="hidden" value="1/1/2013" />

<div id="value">
</div>
```

Select the input's value by calling `.val()` and set the div content by calling `html()`

```
$("#value").html($("#date").val());
```

If you're using this with a datepicker, then use the datepickers `onSelect` event to update when the user selects a date or changes the date.

Do something like this when you declare your datePicker

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(){
         $(".show_date").html($(this).val());
    }
});
```

So everytime the value of the datepicker changes, `.show_date` will have it's html update with the value of the datepicker. You don't really need a hidden field either.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ey8Mz/)

Comment: Heres a live url link to the page:

http://www.shahidmirzadesign.co.uk/stack_overflow/date_picker_edited.html

Comment: @user1514146 You can adapt the code I've shown to your markup. Same concept applies. Select your input, call `.val()`, select your div, set the `html()`. Try that and if you have an issue post an update, but on SO we generally don't write the entire code for you.

Comment: I understand that, but literally I've been staring at it for hours, I know I'm making a silly mistake. Please have a look at the following link:
http://jsfiddle.net/V7ng4/

Comment: @user1514146, you have it backwards. You're getting the value of the div and then putting it into the input. It needs to be the other way around. See http://jsfiddle.net/V7ng4/1/

Comment: Im really confused, the jsfiddle worked, however, in situ, it doesn't respond:
http://www.shahidmirzadesign.co.uk/stack_overflow/date_picker_edited.html

Comment: Right I know what is happening, when you select the date from the calendar, the data is stored in value. However, it won't update the result unless you refresh the page.

Comment: @user1514146, you're only setting the value of the div on the `document.ready` event. You need to do it every time the value changes. See my update to the answer.

Comment: @user1514146, no problem. Please remember that you can accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Would you mind me picking your brain? I thought everything JQuery was client side, so why would it not update instantly before you used the onSelect function

Comment: @user1514146, why would it? The datepicker's purpose is to pick a date, which it does. You click the field, you pick a date, the value of the textbox is updated. If you want to extend that functionality, like displaying the date in a separate HTML control, then you use the hooks provided (like the onSelect). It's better to have the option of extending the functionality, rather than having it do stuff you don't want it to do by default.

Comment: As in, it was stored in the value and then on a page refresh it would then send the value to the span class. I thought it would send it to the span class without refreshing the page

Comment: @user1514146, as I said you only updated the value on page load. When you refreshed the page that script was being called again, this time with the value that browser stored. You **explicitly** said "only do this one time on page load", so that is what it did. It was a coincidence that refreshing the page gave you the result you were looking for. If you want it do it automatically every time it updates, you need to explicitly tell it to do that instead. In any case, we're not supposed to use comments for discussion. If you need a further explanation, you can always ask a new question.